# iMacros run .js file from .js file

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using iMacros to run some code. I want to run existing .js file within a .js file. I tried with

```
iimPlay("macro.js")
```

But it didn't work. I removed the extensions and the result was the same.

Comment: CIM... - Cumbersome and not "Best Practice"... - Was never possible "directly"... (at least using iMacros for FF)...  - Documented in the Wiki where you have some Workaround explained... (And several Threads on the iMacros Forum...)

Comment: You could find that Workaround by yourself btw, if you pay a little bit some "attention" to what "happens" when you remove the Extension...

Comment: I tried. I used 2 simple scripts. The second script was suppose to alert but nothing happened.

Comment: Yeah, but what did you try...? The Syntax you mentioned in your Qt doesn't work, like documented in the Wiki... - Did you check the Wiki...? (=> about the 'iimPlay()' Command) and did you try the "official" Workaround...?

Comment: I found a solution. Adding macro to bookmarks and using that bookmark link as URL works just fine.

Comment: Ah OK!, I first thought you meant calling your Macro as a Base54 Embedded Macro which would be even more cumbersome than your original Idea..., but OK, yep, using the 'imacros://run/?m=' Syntax in 'URL GOTO' from some on-the-fly generated '.iim' Macro in your '.js' Script is indeed the "official" Workaround documented in the Wiki... - But again, this "Construction" of calling a '.js' from a '.js' is a bit of a "dirty" Solution in my Opinion, you are an Advanced User, you may want to review the overall Implementation of your "Scenario"/Script one day...

Comment: Oops, Typo: "Base54" = "Base64" of course...